# Resharper 8.1. Add to abbreviations list missing

Tags: resharper, abbreviation

somehow I'm missing the add to abbreviations suggestion in resharper:

[image: Screenshot of missing menu entry]

So, what can I do to reenable it?

Lots of Greetings!

Volker

Comment: `builder` is a better name for your `UriBuilder` variable :)

Answer (score 1):

As I see, ReSharper has never suggested adding anything to abbreviation list for such case. At least I checked it in ReSharper 6.1.1, 7.1.3 and 8.1. According to default naming convention for local variables (ReSharper | Options | Code Editing | C# | Naming Style | Local variables), lowerCamelCase template should be used there for the name.

- if you type a name like "aUBI", ReSharper will suggest adding UBI to the list, because the first letter in the name still is in lower case. Otherwise, it will break naming convention.
- if you change naming style for local variable to UpperCamelCase and the name is still "UBI", ReSharper will suggest adding "UBI" to the list, because it won't break naming convention (first letter in Upper case).

If you consider such behavior like a bug, you are welcome to submit a new ticket to [YouTrack](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=ReSharper).